# Fetch interactive script for a YouTube video

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch the interactive script, if available, for a video from YouTube's Java API but had little success in doing so as I could not find a way to fetch it through API.

So, I tried parsing the page using a HTML parser (searching for element with id = "transcript-scrollbox") after fetching the page using JSoup but this does not work because the page does not contain any element with this id.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(pageUrl).get();

Element transcriptScrollBox = 

doc.select("div[transcript-scrollbox]").first();
//doc.getElementById("div#transcript-scrollbox");
if(transcriptScrollBox!=null)
  System.out.println("element in trnascript = " + transcriptScrollBox.text());
```

For example in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ER8OkqBdpE) on probability from Khan Academy there is a button which displays the interactive script for this video. I fetched the page contents for this URL and then tried searching for the element. Is the interactive script not a part of the page (probably yes as the element transcriptScrollBox was always null). If it's a yes then how do I fetch the data ?

Can anyone point me in the direction or help me in achieving my goal.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried from the YouTube API and the error/problem you encountered?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the phrased the question in a wrong way. As I could not find a way to fetch script through API I thought of parsing the page. Can it be done through API?

Answer (score 0):

We don't publicly expose that data via the YouTube API, and I can't advocate any automated solution that scrapes the YouTube website. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: If you can expose this then it will be awesome to have. In places like I stay; where the net connectivity is not very fast , we can download the video and store it to a repository. Later on some user can use the interactive script to understand those parts of the video where the instructor's voice was not very clear or he was too fast to be understood. Are you planning to add it any time soon ?

Comment: And it would be extremely helpful if the interactive transcripts were included in searches.  Holy smokes, it would make it 100x easier to find things that I wanted!